# Migration SQL Server 2008 to MySQL: Is it possible to avoid conversion?

Tags: sql-server-2008, migration, mysql-workbench, database-migration, collation

I am trying to migrate a SQL Server 2008 database, which uses `latin1` as `collation` `(latin1_general_ci_as).` This database shall be migrated to MySQL 5.6.27:

```
/etc/my.cnf is:
[mysqld]
collation-server=latin1_general_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES latin1'
character-set-server=latin1

[client]
default-character-set=latin1

[mysql]
default-character-set=latin1
```

For migration I used *MySQL Workbench*. The schema can be created very well, but it always creates the schema with collation *utf8* and charset *utf8_general_ci*. And so it tries also to convert the data from latin1 to utf8. This does not work because data copy gets several errors (data can't be converted)

> **Question**: Is there a way to avoid the conversion in general? For me it would be fine if the target database would use collation latin1
>   as well.
>
> If that isn't possible it would be great if somebody can tell me how I
>   can copy the data correctly.

Comment: Please provide a little bit more details, like: on which platform you run WB, what's the version of WB?

Comment: Windows 7 64 Bit and the version of the WB is 6.3.5.
Any thoughts, recommendations or tricks are welcome

Comment: I don't have the answer, but WB 6.3.6 did make some improvements in this regard. Give it a try. Also, for the source connection, does Advanced have an option similar to "Driver sends Unicode data as UTF-8"? It does on Linux, I've not tested Windows in awhile.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not help. The option you mention is only available if you use the FreeTDS driver. Tried that one too, but it did not help  as well (tried it activated or deactivated. 

Meanwhile I went back to "if the migration want to migrate to utf8 then we use utf8" and changed the configuration back to utf8 and utf8_general_ci, but then I get the error message "incorrect string..." for each german Umlaut like ä,ö,ü and I guess for many more characters